# How to get return only specified fields with a find() / query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Currently I am using

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
```

and it returns complete entries of the table posts but how can I get only partial entries. Some thing like

```
SELECT body,title FROM posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the "fields" option and specify (in an array) what fields you want to retrieve.

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('body', 'title')
));
```

I hate to be the guy that writes this, cause it usually bothers me, but I think this question is worth of "RTM".

This page in the book explains it all:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I do accept that it is very basic but for some reason my browser is giving me an error   Error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Post your code at http://bin.cakephp.org/ then paste the link in your comments.  Likely just a minor syntax error that I can pinpoint for you.

Comment: because array is spelled as arrray, could not edit, because of only being a single char edit.

Comment: thanks very much i tried some thing similar before you posted with correct array spelling. Something else must have gone wrong.

Comment: @Ceeram:  LOL at my spelling... "arrray".  Good catch.  Changed it in the answer.  TY